# Best way to map a JSON string to a custom enum case without having access to the enums implementation in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, enums, codable

Consider the following simple JSON:

```
{
  "title": "Some title",
  "subtitle": "Some subtitle",
  "button_type": "rounded"
}
```

This is my current approach towards decoding the buttonType field:

```
// I dont have access to this enums implementation as it comes from a 3rd party lib.
enum ButtonType {
    case squared
    case simple
    case rounded
    case normal
}

struct ResponseModel: Decodable {
    var title: String
    var subtitle: String
    var type: ButtonType
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title = "title"
        case subtitle = "subtitle"
        case type = "button_type"
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        subtitle = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .subtitle)
        let stringType = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
        switch stringType {
        case "squared":
            type = .squared
        case "simple":
            type = .simple
        case "rounded":
            type = .rounded
        default:
            type = .normal
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any prettier way to accomplish decoding the string to the custom enum without that nasty switch statement iterating over a plain string?. I sadly do not have access to the enums implementation as it comes from a third party library. If I did I would just make the enum conform to String & Codable and have Codable work its magic, but I dont.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own `enum`

```
enum MyButtonType: String {
    case squared
    case simple
    case rounded
    case normal

    var toButtonType: ButtonType {
         switch self {
              case .squared: return .squared
              case .simple: return .simple
              case .rounded: return .rounded
              case .normal: return .normal
         }
    }
}
```

Then change

```
 var type: ButtonType
```

To

```
 var type: MyButtonType
```

And when you need the custom `enum` just use

```
responseModel.type.toButtonType
```

The `String` after the `:` in the enum makes it conform to `RawRepresentable<String>` you won’t need the custom `init` anymore.

You can also manually conform to `RawPresentable<String> but it requires all the` String` entries.

```
extension ButtonType: RawRepresentable {
    typealias RawValue = String
    var rawValue: String {
        switch self {
        case .squared:
            return "squared"
        case .simple:
            return "simple"
        case .rounded:
            return "rounded"
        case .normal:
            return "normal"
        }
    }
    
    init?(rawValue: String) {
        switch rawValue {
        case "squared":
            self = .squared
        case "simple":
            self = .simple
        case "rounded":
            self = .rounded
        case "normal":
            self = .normal
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

With this you don't have to change the Type in the model.

Comment: This seems to work fine. Thank you! Wondering whether there is any way to avoid having to use a switch statement and having to "duplicate" the same enum to be able to convert it from one type to another.

Comment: Try “extension ButtonType:String {} “ and see if it works @stompy

Comment: I did try exactly that before making this thread haha! Sadly you get a compiler error with "Inheritance from non-protocol type 'String'" :(

Comment: @stompy I thought that would be the case, this is probably the only way then. You can suggest the 3rd party adds it to a future release.

Comment: Im afraid you're right. Anyway, your approach is far more cleaner than switching over a plain string as I was doing. Your answer has been marked as accepted. Thanks! :)

Comment: @stompy thank you. Did you click on the green check mark too?

Comment: I did now! Sorry .

Answer (score 1):

Just another solution.

Even if you don't control the how `ButtonType` is defined, you can still conform it to `Decodable` using an extension.

### Step 1: Conform `ButtonType` to `Decodable`

```
extension ButtonType: Decodable {
  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
    let text = try container.decode(String.self)
    switch text {
    case "squared": self = .squared
    case "simple": self = .simple
    case "rounded": self = .rounded
    case "normal": self = .normal
    default: throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(.init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Cannot initialize ButtonType from invalid String value \(text)"))
    }
  }
}
```

### Step 2: Use it in your `ResponseModel`

```
struct ResponseModel: Decodable {
    var title: String
    var subtitle: String
    var type: ButtonType
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title = "title"
        case subtitle = "subtitle"
        case type = "button_type"
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought of this one yes! However if someone else on my team wants to extend this 3rd party enum with Decodable as well (with maybe another decoding strategy or whatever), both extensions would conflict. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's already two pretty good answers, summarized as:

1. Create your own enum that mirrors the main one, and serialize it however you want. This has the maintenance burden of keeping your mirror in sync with the main one.
2. Conform the main enum to `Decodable`. This is less maintenance work, but it's kinda risky. You should avoid conforming types you don't control (e.g. `ButtonType`) to protocols you don't control (e.g. `Decodable`), because it's possible that somebody else has written a conflicting conformance.

There's an alternative trick that I've found to be *really* handy. You can create a PropertyWrapper, and give it the customized codable behaviour.

```swift
@propertyWrapper struct CustomDecodableButtonType {
  let wrappedValue: ButtonType // 1. Define a wrapper for third party type
}

// 2. Define your own decoding logic for it
extension CustomDecodableButtonType: Decodable {
  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
    let text = try container.decode(String.self)
    switch text {
      case "squared": self.init(wrappedValue: .squared)
      case "simple" : self.init(wrappedValue: .simple)
      case "rounded": self.init(wrappedValue: .rounded)
      case "normal" : self.init(wrappedValue: .normal)
      default: throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(.init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Cannot initialize ButtonType from invalid String value \(text)"))
    }
  }
}

struct ResponseModel: Decodable {
  var title: String
  var subtitle: String
  // 3. Wrap whichever fields you need.
  @CustomDecodableButtonType var type: ButtonType
}
```

Comment: Oh wow. Ive never delved into solutions that involved property wrappers. This is super handy. Thanks!

Comment: @stompy Yeah, it's a really powerful feature. Well not really a feature on its own, but a really natural interplay between two other features (property wrappers, and Codable). Providing codable implementations for foreign types has been one place where it comes in really useful. Another useful case is if you have one type, which gets encoded in different ways for different uses (e.g. two different APIs want the same data, but have two different formats they expect).